# The relevant error-causing widget was Column

Tags: flutter

the error says "The relevant error-causing widget was Column", and i dont know how to solve that, can anyone have idea to solve this problem?

this is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = buildAppBar();
    // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
    final tdListWidget = Container(
      child: ListTodo(todolist),
    );
    final pageBody = SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...buildPotraitContent(appBar, tdListWidget),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: pageBody,
            floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => startAddNewTodo(context),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know 'buildPotraitContent' method insdie.

Comment: check the return type of `buildPotraitContent`